# Can't break out of while loop in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, break

The purpose of my code is to find the amount of people where the probability that at least 2 of them have the same birthday is 50%.

```
source('colMatches.r')
all_npeople = 1:300
days = 1:365
ntrials = 1000
sizematch = 2

N = length(all_npeople)

counter = 1
pmean = rep(0,N)

while (pmean[counter] <= 0.5)
{
  npeople = all_npeople[counter]
  x = matrix(sample(days, npeople*ntrials, replace=TRUE),nrow=npeople,
             ncol=ntrials)
  w = colMatches(x, sizematch)
  pmean[counter] = mean(w)
  counter = counter + 1
}

s3 = toString(pmean[counter])
s2 = toString(counter)
s1 = "The smallest value of n for which the probability of a match is at least 0.5 is equal to "
s4 = " (the test p value is "
s5 = "). This means when you have "
s6 = " people in a room the probability that two of them have the same birthday is 50%."
paste(s1, s2, s4, s3, s5, s2, s6, sep="")
```

When I run that code I get "The smallest value of n for which the probability of a match is at least 0.5 is equal to 301 (the test p value is NA). This means when you have 301 people in a room the probability that two of them have the same birthday is 50%." So the while statement isn't working properly for some reason. It's cycling all the way through all_npeople even though it should stop when pmean[counter] is no longer less than or equal to 0.5.

I know that pmean is updating correctly though because when I test it afterwards pmean[50] = 0.971. So that list is indeed correct but the while loop still won't end.

*colmatches is a function that determines if a column has a certain number of matches based on sizematch. So in this case it's looking at the matrix defined in x and listing 1 for every column that has at least 2 similar values and 0 for every column with no matches.

Comment: To answer your question concerning why the while loop is not exiting properly is your counter<-counter+1 statement is before the return of the while loop.  At the end of the loop, the counter increments and mean[counter] is equal to your initial default setting of 0.  Without the code to colmatch, I can't test to confirm.  Depending on how colmatch is written you could most likely eliminate counter and the loop completely.

Answer (score 6):

I admire your attempt to program this question, but the beauty of R is most of this work is done for you:

```
qbirthday(prob = 0.5, classes = 365, coincident = 2)
#answer is 23 people.
```

You maybe also be interested in:

```
pbirthday(n, classes = 365, coincident = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Today is my first time experimenting with R though and regardless of if there's an easier way I'm still concerned that my while loop isn't working. I think there's something wrong with the test expression but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the code is only to define number of people when probability that at least two of them have same birthday is above 0.5, it is possible to write it in much simplier way:

```
# note that probability below is probability of NOT having same birthday

probability <- 1
people <- 1
days <- 365

while(probability >= 0.5){
    people <- people + 1
    probability <- probability * (days + 1 - people) / days
}

print(people)
```